# How to capture http request/response traffic results

Tags: http, request, capture, traffic

I want to Capture Http Request/Response Traffic results(URL,Method,Type etc) with c# Windows Form App as manually.

An Example :
Run ie explorer-> Tools -> F12 Developer Tools->Network Tab-Star Capture

How can I solve this problem. (Any use of the sdk. winpcap etc)
How to trace a road?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below:

```
...
HttpWebRequest request =(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(<url>));
...
try
{
     HttpWebResponse response =(HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
     WebHeaderCollection headers = response.Headers;
     ...
}
catch(WebException exc) { "HTTP EXCEPTION: " + exc.Message +" " + exc.Status; }
catch(ProtocolViolationException exc) { exc.Message; }
catch(UriFormatException exc)         { exc.Message; }
catch(NotSupportedException exc)      { exc.Message; }
catch(IOException exc)                { exc.Message; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest.:)
I will try.

Comment: How Can I List all Headers Values(URL,Type) in Response Headers?
I tried the following.

for (int I = 0; I < headers.Count-1; I++)
  {
     string[] values = headers.GetValues(I);
     foreach (string value in values)
      {
       textBox1.Text += value + Environment.NewLine;
      }
  }

Comment: WebHeaderCollection headers = response.Headers;
    for (int i=0; i < headers.Count; i++)                
        Console.WriteLine ("\t" + headers.GetKey(i) + " = " + headers.Get(i));

Comment: How Can I make without using that HttpListener and proxy?
could you please help me ?ıs there any examples....like codes etc...?
thanks in advance :)

Comment: I want to http network traffic capture with c#.? 
But no using httplistener class.
Because httplistener need to proxy settigs.
I don't want to make proxy settings.
As Below;
___http://e1201.hizliresim.com/t/k/1vl3y.png

How Can I access Network Tab in results(URL,Method,Type)?
thanks in advance :)